# Help to find all different cases need for proof about homomorphism from Z to R

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am a bit confused about why my professor approached the following a certain way, and also why it cannot be done differently.

The question is to prove that for any ring R we there is a unique homomorphism $$\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to R$$

Now here is my approach:

Define $\phi(0)=0_{R}$ and $\phi(1)=1_{R}$

and define $\phi(x)=x\phi(1)$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Then it is just a matter of verification that

$\phi(x+y)=(x+y)\phi(1)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$

and $\phi(xy)=xy\phi(1)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$

as integers all obey these rules and we are just applying ring axioms.

However, the proof given in class took into account seemingly endless many cases

for example $x,y \ge 0$ and $\phi(x+y)$

$x,y \ge 0$ and $\phi(-x-y)$

$x,y \ge 0$ and $x \ge y$ etc

I am having a lot of trouble understanding why this is needed at all, and why we cannot just do the general case. Furthermore I am not even sure if I were to do it by cases what all the different cases would be.

Does anyone have any insight or opinions for me?

Thanks

Update:

I am just going to learn the proof using cases as it seems not doing so only makes things even more complicated .
I am now looking for someone to help me to understand all the diffirent cases I must consider

Comment: You don't need all those cases. You just need to show that $\phi$, as you defined it, is a homomorphism and that if $\psi$ is any other homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to $R$ then it must be equal to $\phi$.

Comment: And is showing it is one similar to how I did ? Could you maybe make it as an answer because this seems like what I am wanting to do

Answer (score 1):

You say that "this is just a matter of verification", but you need to define $x\phi(1)$ recursively, using the homomorphism property. Therefore we have $\phi(1)=1_R$, and then we conclude that $\phi(n)=\sum_{1=1}^n\phi(1)$ for all positive $n$. Indeed $\phi(2)=\phi(1+1)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)$, etc. Also $\phi(0)=0$ and then $\phi(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{|n|}-\phi(1)$ for all negative $n$.

Comment: Hm thanks , so could you maybe elaborate on what you are saying with this then ?

Comment: Ie, I am not sure what this means. Is it saying I am on the right track or am wrong. As it is now I really dont know what you are saying with this answer

Comment: There is a mistake when defining $\phi(n)$ for negative $n$. You should have that $\phi(n)$ is additive inverse of the sum you give.

Comment: @Wojowu Of course, a typo. I fixed it !

Answer (score 0):

How do you define $x\phi(1)$, for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$?  Maybe you are taking for granted that this is already defined, but if you think about how you would define it rigorously, you would probably do something like the following.  Define $x\phi(1)$ for $x\geq 0$ by induction via the formula $$(x+1)\phi(1)=x\phi(1)+\phi(1),$$ and then define $x\phi(1)$ to be the additive inverse of $(-x)\phi(1)$ if $x<0$.  If you use this definition, then to prove a statement like $(x+y)\phi(1)=x\phi(1)+y\phi(1)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, you will necessarily have to split into cases according to the signs of $x$, $y$, and $x+y$, since the very definition of the expressions involved are given by splitting into cases.

If you can give a definition of $x\phi(1)$ that does not treat the cases $x\geq 0$ and $x<0$ separately, you can avoid having to consider cases here, but it is not obvious how you would make such a definition.

Comment: Oh okay , so how many cases would there actually be then ?

Comment: Well, a priori, there will be $2^3=8$ cases: each of the three numbers $x$, $y$, and $x+y$ could be either $\geq 0$ or $<0$.  But some of them are obviously impossible (for instance, if $x$ and $y$ are positive, then $x+y$ can't be negative), and some can be reduced to other cases by symmetry (for instance, the case where $x$ is positive, $y$ is negative, and $x+y$ is positive isn't really different from the case where $x$ is negative, $y$ is positive, and $x+y$ is positive, because you can just swap $x$ and $y$).

Comment: So the cases with x and y positive and x-y greater and less then zero and x+y and then the cases of one less than zero and the other greater, and then the cases of both less?